# Fiori elements show pop up message upon action

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori, sap-cap

we have implemented a Fiori elements based application using CAP(CDS annotations). We have a table containing a field with a mediatype property. The property renders as a Link as expected, allowing us to click the link and download the file content. Similarly the upload is also rendered by the standard framework. Upon clicking the link, a new browser tab opens temporarily until the file downloads in the background, and then closes automatically.

We have a requirement to display a customized pop up message upon upload & download(click of the link). The standard handler functions of req.notify() or req.warn() do not work as expected and the messages are not displayed even though the function is executed(checked in debug mode).

Any ideas or suggestions on how to achieve the functionality without doing a custom extension?

Thank you in advance!

[Fiori UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejFUz.png)

[service definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiU3V.png)

[annotations.cds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FR455.png)

We have tried using the standard handler methods provided by the framework but they did not work.